# Is there any keyboard hotkey to undo hiding an application?

Tags: macos, keyboard, applications

I use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to hide applications all the time. Sometimes I really want to undo that action, but pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> again will just hide the now active application.

Pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> doesn't do it either.

I don't know if there's a way to do this built into OSX, but if not I wouldn't be opposed to installing an application that would provide this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will let you go through all the running applications, even if it's hidden. More tricks are discussed at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/196141/keyboard-shortcut-to-unhide-or-unminimize-a-window-in-os-x).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. I didn't even think of `Command+Tab` because I associate it with cycling through active applications. The hidden application is the most recently active, so it will be the first result.